# Load mobile version of website when viewing with certain browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible for the mobile version of my site to be loaded based on browser. Chrome doesn't respond well to certain effects I have on my site, and was wondering if I could get my simplified, mobile version to load. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the difference (from the browser's perspective) between the mobile version and the normal one? Are the two different sites (i.e. `m.mywebsite.com` vs. `www.mywebsite.com`), or is it just different css/scripts?

Comment: It's just a different script.

Comment: How does the browser decide which script to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Comment: The screen size determines whether to use mobile or full version

Comment: Please post some code!  Where is the app deciding which assets to load?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window.matchMedia(media query):

```
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 500px)").matches) {
    /* The viewport is less than, or equal to, 500 pixels wide */
} else {
    /* The viewport is greater than 500 pixels wide */
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia